# Hyperarithemtic statements decidable by induction up to a recursive ordinal  

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Kleene's O is a $\Pi_1^1$ complete set that decides every hyperarithmetic statement. A Turing Machine that uses this set as an oracle to decide a hyperarithmetic question can only look at a finite segment of the oracle before making a decision. The possible questions are all of the form $n$ is or is not a notation for a recursive ordinal. Can every hyperarithmetic question be decided by a single notation for a sufficiently large recursive ordinal?

Comment: Paul, it appears that your question is a little vague. Ali Enayat and I interpreted it in two different ways. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean.

Comment: I left a comment on François' answer to indicate my interpretation of your question, which might not coincide with your intended question, so please leave a comment on François' answer to clarify the situation.

Comment: My underlying question is: can every hyperarithmetic question be decided by induction up to some recursive ordinal?

Comment: @Paul Budnik: I still don't understand exactly what you're asking, so it might be helpful to state it more formally.  Possibly the following fact is helpful: if $S$ is hyperarithmetic then there is an ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1^{CK}$ such that for each $n$ there is an ordering $\prec_n$ (uniformly computable from $n$) such that $n\in S$ iff $ot(\prec_n)<\alpha$.

Comment: ... but there is no ordinal which does that for all hyperarithmetic sentences. So we are confused as to the sequence of queries and replies here. I thought like François: you are given a hyperarithmetic set and a number, you pick a notation and ask the oracle, it tells you whether it is well-founded, then you answer whether the number belongs to the set. 

Comment: I decided to accept the helpful answer to what was an ambiguous question. I do not fully understand the comment by Henry Towsner. I am not sure what `$ot(\prec_n)$' means and would appreciate a reference for this fact that may answer my question. If not, I may resubmit a more carefully worded question. 





Comment: $ot(\prec_n)$ is the order-type of the ordering $\prec_n$ (that is, the unique ordinal which is the height of $\prec_n$).  The fact I described is the main part of the proof of the equivalence of $\Delta_1^1$ and hyperarithmetic sets.  (See, for instance, Pohlers' lecture notes on recursion theory: wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/logik/Veroeffentlichungen/lec/Pohlers/rekursionstheorie.ps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every $\Pi^1_1$ set is many-one reducible to Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$. In particular, the universal $\Pi^1_1$ set is many-one reducible to Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$. Therefore, every $\Pi^1_1$ sentence (and in particular hyperarithmetical sentences) can be decided by making a single query to Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: I thought the question is asking whether there is a recursive ordinal $\alpha$ such that every hyperarithmetical question can be answered by a Turing machine that has access to an oracle that can tell whether a given notation describes $\alpha$ or not. 

Comment: The wording of the question is a little vague. I see how you could read the question that way. I will ask the OP to clarify.

Comment: I forgot to add that under my interpretation the answer to the question is negative based on Kleene's theorem that describes hyperarithmetic sets as those constructed along branches of $\cal{O}$ using the jump operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Neither it nor the comment is quite the question I intended, but the answer helps. The question I intended is can you get the same answer as the TM with oracle given only a sufficiently large ordinal notation? This means you are able to decide an arbitrarily large initial segment of the oracle given a sufficiently large ordinal notation. Your answer means you only need to decide one question given a sufficiently large ordinal notation.